# XCode: Can't compile StoryBoard (ibtool exit code 10) for an old project - swift 3 and pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Hi there and thanks for your time in advance.

A project have been passed to me via bitbucket to be reuploaded to App Store cause they are removing old projects. My plan is to switch to swift 4 and reupload but I just can't compile it.

Error: Compile Storyboard file Main.storyboard, Command /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 10

Full log:

```
CompileStoryboard dots/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
    cd /XXX/XXX/MY_APP
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --companion-strings-file es:/XXX/XXX/MY_APP/dots/es.lproj/Main.strings --module MY_APP --output-partial-info-plist /XXX/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-cpkrmbiheoxfcvfqrcscruzfeeou/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MY_APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MY_APP.build/Base.lproj/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 9.3 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /XXX/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-cpkrmbiheoxfcvfqrcscruzfeeou/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MY_APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MY_APP.build/Base.lproj /XXX/XXX/MY_APP/dots/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
```

What I have tried so far:

- I have 2 xcode versions but I'm working with Xcode 10.1 to try to compile and switch to swift 4.
- I have set Workspace settings to legacy build system, with the new one I have the same problem.
- Remove Derived Data, deep clean project, restart Xcode and Mac, use Run instead of build...

Nothing works for me...

Logs in DiagnosticReports:

```
Process:               ibtoold [7924]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.1 (14460.46)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks_Fall2018-14460046000000000~5 (10B61)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Exited process [7922]
Responsible:           Xcode [7897]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-17 12:04:31.8061 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.6 (20G165)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        DEF3A9CD-956D-4794-92C6-709F2B99B547

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D2AF19AB-88D2-4C27-A145-18C56D40E306

Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       631 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff237eb3a9
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 10 Bus error: 10
Terminating Process:   exc handler [7924]

VM Region Info: 0x7fff237eb3a9 is in 0x7fff23600000-0x7fff23800000;  bytes after start: 2012073  bytes before end: 85078
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      __TEXT                   7fff22c42000-7fff23600000 [ 9976K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ions/C/AppKit
--->  __TEXT                   7fff23600000-7fff23800000 [ 2048K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  ...ions/C/AppKit
      __TEXT                   7fff23800000-7fff2398e000 [ 1592K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ions/C/AppKit

Application Specific Information:




Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libMainThreadChecker.dylib             0x114bc6069 swizzleImplementationFast + 115
1   libMainThreadChecker.dylib             0x114bc5ef0 addSwizzler + 165
2   libMainThreadChecker.dylib             0x114bc5ae6 __library_initializer + 2939
3   dyld                                   0x10ebcb8d3 ImageLoaderMachO::doImageInit(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 307
4   dyld                                   0x10ebcbf47 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 29
5   dyld                                   0x10ebc6ae6 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 492
6   dyld                                   0x10ebc489f ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 191
7   dyld                                   0x10ebc4940 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 82
8   dyld                                   0x10ebb4a12 dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 82
9   dyld                                   0x10ebc011a dlopen_internal + 616
10  libdyld.dylib                       0x7fff2039fc94 dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 185
11  libdyld.dylib                       0x7fff2038e07e dlopen + 28
12  IDEFoundation                          0x10a5cb01e _IDEInitializeMainThreadChecker + 400
13  IDEFoundation                          0x10a5cba59 IDEInitialize + 1021
14  ibtoold                                0x108e555b0 IBIDEInitialize + 52
15  ibtoold                                0x108e546dc main + 1744
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x7fff2039df3d start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff2037e420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff2037e420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff2034d2ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7fff2034d62c mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff2047a49f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff20478b7f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff20477f8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7fff204fe8b2 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   ibtoold                                0x108e5ee14 -[IBCLIServerRelocationDetector startOnNewThread] + 215
7   Foundation                          0x7fff21202437 __NSThread__start__ + 1068
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff203828fc _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7fff2037e443 thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000100  rbx: 0x00007fff7ba77068  rcx: 0x00007fff7f1ca198  rdx: 0x00007fff7efca198
  rdi: 0x0000000114bc6efe  rsi: 0x0000000000000100  rbp: 0x00007ffee6db54d0  rsp: 0x00007ffee6db54b0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000004  r10: 0x0000000000000005  r11: 0x1fe68ea783c00698
  r12: 0x0000000114b9c838  r13: 0x00007fff237eb399  r14: 0x0000000114b9c838  r15: 0x00007fff237eb399
  rip: 0x0000000114bc6069  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007fff237eb3a9
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000007 (invalid protections for user data write)
Trap Number:     14

Thread 0 instruction stream:
  48 83 3d df 14 1c 00 ff-75 7a 48 85 db 74 60 48  H.=.....uzH..t`H
  39 1d 89 14 1c 00 74 57-48 39 1d 88 14 1c 00 74  9.....tWH9.....t
  4e 48 39 1d 87 14 1c 00-74 45 48 39 1d 86 14 1c  NH9.....tEH9....
  00 74 3c 48 39 1d 85 14-1c 00 74 33 48 39 1d 84  .t<H9.....t3H9..
  14 1c 00 74 2a 48 39 1d-83 14 1c 00 74 21 48 39  ...t*H9.....t!H9
  1d 82 14 1c 00 74 18 48-39 1d 81 14 1c 00 74 0f  .....t.H9.....t.
 [4d]89 77 10 48 83 c4 08-5b 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 4c  M.w.H...[A^A_].L <==
  89 ff 4c 89 f6 48 83 c4-08 5b 41 5e 41 5f 5d e9  ..L..H...[A^A_].
  3b 03 00 00 48 8d 3d 5c-14 1c 00 48 8d 35 c5 12  ;...H.=\...H.5..
  00 00 e8 b6 02 00 00 e9-6e ff ff ff 55 48 89 e5  ........n...UH..
  53 50 48 8b 3d ce 13 1c-00 e8 2f 03 00 00 48 89  SPH.=...../...H.
  c3 48 85 db 75 21 bf 01-00 00 00 be 10 00 00 00  .H..u!..........

Binary Images:
       0x114b9b000 -        0x114bc6fff libMainThreadChecker.dylib (*) <d639f3ed-4579-344d-a181-4d9e9c6a9446> /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib
       0x10ebae000 -        0x10ec49fff dyld (*) <0cc19410-fd43-39ae-a32a-50273f8303a4> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff20388000 -     0x7fff203c3fff libdyld.dylib (*) <3de0178a-0aee-3d08-ae19-6c6403f69ba1> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
       0x10a4c4000 -        0x10acf0fff IDEFoundation (*) <105eab4b-a2ae-3b9e-bc0e-973b6b87a429> /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x108e43000 -        0x108e72fff ibtoold (*) <dc6d5327-4716-3968-8390-312d22fea281> /Applications/Xcode_10-1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold
    0x7fff2037c000 -     0x7fff20387fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <1268ff2d-a513-3b51-ba65-af2ff5789ddb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff2034c000 -     0x7fff2037bfff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <78289aae-61b5-339f-a485-8819bc2388f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff203fa000 -     0x7fff20897fff CoreFoundation (*) <8cf9d741-adff-3d5e-acde-dc342701ee0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff211a9000 -     0x7fff21507fff Foundation (*) <7b7fb88b-01d3-38ce-8029-837db094c545> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff22c42000 -     0x7fff2398dfff AppKit (*) <02ec69a0-d634-341b-be3d-840f496f5814> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.0G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.0G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=82.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=82.3M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Dispatch continuations            32.0M        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            37.3M       22 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        4 
Stack                             9752K        4 
VM_ALLOCATE                        208K        3 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            38.6M      573 
__DATA_CONST                      28.0M      310 
__DATA_DIRTY                      1750K      216 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       540.4M      100 
__OBJC_RO                         70.3M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2496K        2 
__TEXT                           532.4M      552 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                       30.8M        2 
shared memory                       40K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.3G     1803
```

Comment: So you can open the storyboard and edit it, but you can't compile it?

Comment: Yes, I can open Main and LaunchScreen storyboard but it does not compile...It's driving me crazy

Comment: Try different compatibility settings for the storyboard format.

Comment: Thanks for your help, not sure of what you mean I'm very new to xcode and swift, I have changed the type to objective-c just to try something but there are code errors. I have also changed builds for and opens in with no luck.

Comment: Well, in the worst case scenario you could just reconstruct the storyboard by hand.